# How Surya and Chandra freed from Rahu, according to the scriptures?

Tags: identification-request, surya, chandra, rahu

Most of us know that Rahu is the reason of solar/lunar esclipse. But, Does any scriptures mention that how Surya and Chandra freed from Rahu?